# Find a directory with a prefix in name

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have one big directory, that contains many subdirectories whose names are staring with 13xxx,10xxx,11xxx and so on. These directories contains text files with a name my_file.txt.
Now the problem is, I want to change the files in the directories 13xxx and 11xxx only and don't want to touch files in 10xxx directories.
I am trying to search directories with:

```
[ -d "13*"] && ..
[ -d "13"*] && ..
```

But seems like it doesn't work like this.
Can anyone provide a small code that solves this riddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for-loop and globbing like:

```
for d in 1[13]*; do
    do_something "$d/my_file.txt";
done
```

or

```
for f in 1[13]*/my_file.txt; do
    do_something "$f";
done
```

Comment: This is performing operation to every file in every directory. So all files from 11xxx, 10xxx and 13xxx were changed.

Comment: Thanks man for the hint. I figured it out from the hint you have given.

Comment: Strange, should work fine exactly like this and 10xxxx should not be included. Maybe you did something wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was :

```
for d in 11*/; do
    echo "#Text to be added" >> "$d"/my_file.txt;
done
for d in 13*/; do
    echo "#Text to be added" >> "$d"/my_file.txt;
done
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept this as the answer to your question.